# Dynamically disable mat-option when there is only one option selected in a mat-select

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a mat-select allowing multiple selections where at least one option must be selected at all time. To provide a good UX, when there is only one option that is selected in the mat-select, I want to disable this specific option only (hence have it greyed out) to prevent the user from deselecting it which would lead to having no option(s) selected. As soon as more than one mat-option is selected, I want to automatically re-enable the previously disabled mat-option.

So initially the mat-select looks like this :

[image]

When the user deselects only one of the three options, nothing should happen. But when the user deselects an option an that this "deselection" leads to only have one selected option, I want the mat-select to look like this (disabling the remaining option but keeping the de-selected options enabled) :

[image]

As soon as the user re-selects an option an that there is no longer only one option selected, all the mat-options should be enabled.

[image]

Somehow I am unable to achieve the desired result. As soon as I have only one option selected, the entire mat-select gets disabled prevent the user from even re-selecting another mat-option.

Here is the code I am using :

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of optionsArray"
            [value]="option" 
            [disabled]="this.exampleForm.controls['dropDown'].value.length < 2">
  {{option}}
</mat-option>
```

I recreated my issue in a minimal StackBlitz showing the structure I used in my project (using FormControls, FormGroups, etc.)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3tsyok?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you

PS. For anyone wondering, I created these screenshots by manipulating the CSS via Chrome DevTools, I didn't actually manage to successfully achieve the desired result.

Comment: IMHO a good UX wouldn't disable an option just to be sure there is at least one option selected but just display an error message under the select input if the required conditions are not met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a condition to your `mat-option` loop to ensure only the option that is selected is disabled:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of optionsArray" 
 [value]="option" 
 [disabled]="exampleForm.controls['dropDown'].value.length < 2 && 
      exampleForm.controls['dropDown'].value[0] === option">
 {{option}}
</mat-option>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z3lret?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much